# Hibernate to get max id and store it in memory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to using hibernate. I have written the following code get the max id in my order table.

```
 public int getOrderMaxUID() {
     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
     String query = "SELECT max(o.UID) FROM Order o";
     List list = session.createQuery(query).list();
     int maxOrderUID = ((Integer) list.get(0)).intValue();

     return maxOrderUID;
 }
```

and I call this method in my controller before I add a new record to the table.

```
orderService.getOrderMaxUID();
orderService.add(o);
```

**The Issue :** Records are added to our Order table by other processes as well. So to avoid Duplicate PK issue, I get the max id from the order table before inserting record. But I still get following error when other process add records

```
2013-04-04 09:27:24,841 WARN  ["ajp-bio-8009"-exec-2]     org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 2627, SQLState: S1000
2013-04-04 09:27:24,841 ERROR ["ajp-bio-8009"-exec-2]     org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Order'.     Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Order'. The duplicate key value is (1001508).
```

and

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: Hibernate flushing: could not insert:
```

I want hibernate to store the id retrieved by getMaxOrderId() method in memory and use the next number as when adding new record.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Dumb question: do you increment the MAX id or at least use a new ID for your new entity? I don't have enough context here... Can you provide the method in your controller? Does it fail only with multiple processes or even with a single process? What do you call process (thread?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you get Hibernate to just generate the ID for you?

```
/** The id. */
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

EDIT:

You can create entries from multiple processes as long as you do it through hibernate and the id's will be adjusted accordingly.

Inserting into the database outside of hibernate however, will cause you issues. You may be able to use a Customer ID Generator to work around this. [I found this example that may help](http://danu-javastuff.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/custom-id-generator-class-for-hibernate.html)

If you edit the database outside of hibernate, you may run into other problems as well (particularly if you use the second level cache for example)

If you use the same `Session`, you will run into issues caused by the first level cache as well.

Comment: I do use the @GeneratedValue to auto generate id's, but if another process enters record in database table or a record is manually entered in the table and then if hibernate tries to add record, the PK already exists and hence throws exception. Thats the purpose of writing getMaxOrder() method but not getting expected results.

Comment: I used the custom generator and it does work for me now. Thanks for your help, drone.ah.